# Not able to create uptimechecks

Tags: google-cloud-platform, stackdriver, google-cloud-stackdriver

While creating uptimechecks i am getting below error**[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eaTXF.png)**

There was an error testing the uptime check config: Eb`

Comment: This might be a front-end issue and not directly an Uptime issue. You could try saving the check and then wait a few minutes to see if it runs successfully. If it does could you please confirm?

Comment: You can use Google Stackdriver / Cloud Monitoring issue tracker to looks for open issues or report a new one https://b.corp.google.com/savedsearches/559785  (via https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers#trackers-list)

Answer (score 0):

This is a product issue, not a question about the product - I recommend using Google's product forums or submitting a support request with them.